# Dialogflow Fulfillment TypeError : Cannot read property 'Parameters'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Hello I'm trying to make a webhook to my mysql database and everything worked perfectly, until I tried to add parameters.

I always get this error in the firebase cloudfunctions

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined
>       at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:17:47)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:783:7
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:766:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

it's pointing to index.js:17 
Here is my code:

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');

const bodypaser = require('body-parser');


process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;
   const emailPar = parameters['email'];
   const namePar    = parameters['name'];
  console.log(emailPar);
  console.log(namePar);


  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    console.log('Inside function welcome');

   return callbackDB().then((rows) =>{
        console.log('inside callabck in welcome function');
        var reply =rows[0].ID;
        var name = rows[0].display_name;
        agent.add(`Welcome to my agent! My ID is: 0` + reply);
        agent.add(`My name is `+ name);

   }).catch((error) =>{
        console.log('In catch ERROR::: ' +error); 
   });

  }
  function Orders(agent){
    return getOrderCallback().then((rows) =>{
        console.log('inside getOrderCallabck in orders function');
        var id =rows[0].order_id;
        var firstname = rows[0].billing_first_name;
        var lastname = rows[0].billing_last_name;
        var email = rows[0].billing_email;
        var ordereditems =rows[0].order_items;
        var dateorder =rows[0].post_date;
        var billing_address = rows[0].billing_address_1 + ' Postcode: '+ rows[0].billing_postcode + ' City : ' + rows[0].billing_city + ' Country: ' + rows[0].billing_state;
        agent.add('Hello there! The current orders made by you are the following: ');
        agent.add(`--Current Orders ---------------------------`);
        agent.add(`Order ID:  `+ id);
        agent.add('For : ' + firstname + ' ' + lastname);
        agent.add(`Contact: ` + email);
        agent.add(`Shipping Address: ` + billing_address);
        agent.add(`Order placed on :` + dateorder);
        agent.add(`Ordered Items : ` + ordereditems);

   }).catch((error) =>{
        console.log('In catch ERROR::: ' +error); 
   });
  }
  function fallback(agent) {
    console.log('Inside function fallback');
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('GetOrdersByEmailAndName', Orders);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

  function getOrderCallback(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        console.log('Inside getOrderCallback');
      try {
        var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
            host:'xxxx',
            user:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            password:'xxxxxxxxx',
            database:'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',});

        mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
            if(!err){
                console.log('DB connection succeeded.');
                console.log('passed parameters : '+ emailPar + ' ' + namePar);
                mysqlConnection.query(`select
                                            p.ID as order_id,
                                            p.post_date,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_first_name,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_last_name,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_address_1,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_2' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_address_2,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_city,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_state,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_postcode,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_tax,
                                            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_paid_date' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as paid_date,
                                            ( select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
                                        from
                                            wp_posts p 
                                            join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
                                            join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
                                        group by
                                            p.ID
                                        HAVING billing_email = ? AND billing_first_name = ?`,[emailPar,namePar],
                 (error,rows,fields)=>{
                    if(!error){
                        console.log(rows);

                        resolve(rows);
                        }
                    else{
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(rows);
                        }
                    });

            }
        else{
            console.log('DB connection failed.');
        }
  });


      }
      catch (err){
        let results = 'error in try-catch';
        console.log(results);
        reject(results);
      }


    });
}


function callbackDB(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
      console.log('Inside callbackDB');

      try {
        var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
            host:'xxxx',
            user:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            password:'xxxxxxxxx',
            database:'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',});
        mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
            if(!err){
                console.log('DB connection succeeded.');
                mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM wp_users',(error,rows,fields)=>{
                    if(!error){
                        console.log(rows);
                        resolve(rows);
                        }
                    else{
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(rows);
                        }
                    });

            }
        else{
            console.log('DB connection failed.');
        }
  });


      }
      catch (err){
        let results = 'error in try-catch';
        console.log(results);
        reject(results);
      }

    });

}
});
```

It means it has something to do with line 17 which is:

> const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;

But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Help or advice would be much appreciated

Comment: On the surface, this looks like it should be ok. You may want to put the two `console.log()` calls before your functions so you can see what `request.body` looks like. If you're still having issues, updating your question to include the contents of `request.body` can help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Prisoner, but before you wrote this comment, I spend an extra 40 mins looking into the logs, and indeed I found the solution in the request.body. Oddly enough request.body.queryResult doesn't work anymore, yet on my other chatbot that uses queryResult to access the parameters still works LOL. So the solution to my problem is to change it to request.body.result.paramters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like you're using Dialogflow v1, which has the parameters at `request.body.result.parameters`. With Dialogflow v2, this has changed to `request.body.queryResult.parameters`.

If you are still using Dialogflow v1, you should change immediately, since it will no longer be supported soon. To do this, go into your settings in https://console.dialogflow.com/ and make sure you have the v2 API set.

[image]

Comment: 100% Correct, I put it back to queryResult and it worked. Thanks!